# How to remove words from one word to another word in string

Tags: c#, string

Let's say the string is "i don't want to see these words."
How can I remove the words between "don't" and "words", so that the string will be "i don't words"
Assume I don't know the words between "don't" and "words".
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do something like this. Find the index of the start word, then the end word, then pull anything not between them.

```
string sentence = "i don't want to see these words";
string startWord = "don't";
string endWord = "words";

int startIndex = sentence.IndexOf(startWord) + startWord.Length;
int endIndex = sentence.IndexOf(endWord);

return sentence.Remove(startIndex) + " " + sentence.Substring(endIndex);
```

This approach, of course, has some caveats, like that you'll want to decide whether to use `IndexOf` or `LastIndexOf`, because those could mean different things. But you should be able to work out which you'd like relatively easily. It's also case-sensitive, so be aware of that. Not to mention, "don't" obviously won't match with "do not" or even "dont," so make sure you're handling whatever cases you need to in order to make it actually work. Also, this isn't strictly whole words, so include terminators if you need.

I also assume there to be a space between them, but that may or may not be the case. You could probably figure out pretty easily what it should actually be.